# Javascript Function is not working in html form - TypeError: total is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple JavaScript function that sums user input. The function is working fine when I tested it without the form tag. But when I use the same code inside the form tag. The console shows the error

> TypeError: total is not a function

my code

```js
function total() {
  a = Number(document.getElementById('qty').value);
  b = Number(document.getElementById('amount').value);
  c = a * b;
  document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = c;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Part Quantity</label>
    <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Part Quantity" min="1" id="qty" onkeyup="total()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Part Price</label>
    <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="Part Price" id="amount" onkeyup="total()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Total Price(in USD)</label>
    <input type="text" name="total" readonly="" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="Total Price" id="totalPrice">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 order-btn">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" name="order">
Order Now
</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have tried this aswell

```
onkeyup="return javascript:total()"
```

which gives me console error. The syntax is stated [javascript function not working in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117900/javascript-function-not-working-in-form)

> SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'

Comment: Try to put your script after the `</form>` tag

Comment: Please rename your function name and try

Comment: Check this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeyup

Comment: cant replicate the same error

Comment: placing script before `<form >` or after `</form>` tag gives the same error.

Comment: please change the type of input to text

Comment: it doesn't have nothing to do with input type, it is related with pre-existing property conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot name a function same as any of the form element's name or id value. In this case, you have an input:

```
<input type="text" name="total" readonly="" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="Total Price" id="totalPrice">
```

And your function is

```
function total
```

It happens because when you are doing,

```
onkeyup="total()"
```

this is as good as (because you can access form elements using DOM APIs),

```
onkeyup="this.form.total()"
```

And in this case, `this.form.total` is not a function, as it is part of the form. Hence you get the error:

```
TypeError: total is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,
Just rename your function name

```js
function calculateTotal() {
  a = Number(document.getElementById('qty').value);
  b = Number(document.getElementById('amount').value);
  c = a * b;
  document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = c;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Part Quantity</label>
    <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Part Quantity" min="1" id="qty" onkeyup="calculateTotal()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Part Price</label>
    <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="Part Price" id="amount" onkeyup="calculateTotal()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Total Price(in USD)</label>
    <input type="text" name="total" readonly="" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="Total Price" id="totalPrice">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 order-btn">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" name="order">
Order Now
</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

input name="total" with function total{} in the same form on you example, so you should change one.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without inline event handlers and a more modern coding style you could  do something like this.

```
    <form>
        <div>
            <label>Part Quantity</label>
            <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Part Quantity" min="1" id="qty" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Part Price</label>
            <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="Part Price" id="amount" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Total Price(in USD)</label>
            <input type="text" name="total" readonly="" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="Total Price" id="totalPrice">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 order-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" name="order">
                Order Now
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        const obj=(id)=>{ return document.getElementById( id ) };
        document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="number"].form-control' ).forEach( input => {
            input.addEventListener('keyup', e=>{
                obj('totalPrice').value=Number( obj('qty').value ) * Number( obj('amount').value )
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Function cannot have same name as pre-existing property. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function#Function_shares_a_name_with_a_pre-existing_property)

When you create form, you get generated HTML Form DOM Object, and every input within that form is child element.
When you create input, and add name attribute, it actually creates property that is named as input's name attribute value and can be accessed using it like this:

`formObject.inputAttributeNameValue`

Sample:

```js
var theForm = document.getElementById("the_form");

console.log(theForm.total);
```

```html
<form id="the_form">
  <div>
  <div>
    <label>Total Price(in USD)</label>
    <input type="text" name="total" readonly="" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="Total Price" id="totalPrice">
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So you must avoid conflict between function names and property names.
Otherwise, it will throw error `TypeError: <functionName> is not a function`.

You will notice that I have changed event to `oninput` that occurs whenever input value is change, so total price will calculate on any change, even changing value with spinner, not only after `onkeyup` event:

```js
//note: function needs to be unique compared to inputs' name values 
function totalPriceCalculated() { 
  a = Number(document.getElementById('qty').value);
  b = Number(document.getElementById('amount').value);
  c = a * b;
  document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = c;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Part Quantity</label>
    <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Part Quantity" min="1" id="qty" oninput="totalPriceCalculated()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Part Price</label>
    <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="Part Price" id="amount" oninput="totalPriceCalculated()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Total Price(in USD)</label>
    <input type="text" name="total" readonly="" class="form-control" min="1" placeholder="Total Price" id="totalPrice">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 order-btn">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" name="order">
Order Now
</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

See more about error caused when function shares a name with pre-existing property: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function#Function_shares_a_name_with_a_pre-existing_property

**Note:** Be careful about function placement in your HTML and scope. It should be placed directly inside of `<head>` or at the bottom, before closing `</body>` tag, but not within `window.onload`